# Angular WebPart doesn't work inside MobileIron

Tags: angular, sharepoint, mobileiron

Our company makes a web-site based on SharePoint, and one of its WebParts is made with Angular. 
It works with any browsers and devices, except Web@Work on a mobile device inside MobileIron infrastructure.

As far as I know Web@Work uses MobileIron for security and management (AppConnect mode). If that infrastructure is absent, it works in standalone mode (non-AppConnect mode) and it is not secured or managed by MobileIron.

So, this WebPart works on Web@Work in standalone mode, but doesn’t inside MobileIron infrastructure.

And also it’s not possible to debug it with that browser. Are there any settings in MobileIron that can cause this problem?

Comment: Do you have access to the MobileIron developer portal?

Comment: Also, can you open other websites when you run Web@Work as part of AppConnect? for example the angular.io website.

Comment: @DArkO No, I don't have access to developer portal. And as far as I know MobileIron is set up inside intranet, only for local usage. So there is no access to other websites. Outside this intranet I can open this WebPart if I run it in my developer environment.

Comment: One thing you can do is register to the dev portal and request a test instance after you get access. you can set-up the instance and try for yourself. https://info.mobileiron.com/developer_portal_access_request_form_agreement_reg.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have an issue with Web@Work, but rather with the AppTunnel which is a VPN functionality inside of AppConnect.

If your app requires a VPN in order to work than this is what is causing an issue if it's not configured properly.

If you are in contact with the admins that manage the MobileIron platform then you can try these things:

- Try to remove all the tunnel rules for your app and test from their local environment. Also make sure the app is accessible on the device through a normal browser like Safari or Chrome when doing this.
- You might need to set-up some of the tunnel rules inside the MobileIron Admin Panel. you should talk to the customer in order to do this. If they don't know maybe they should reach out to MobileIron support to help with the configuration.

They might have configured rules for the VPN inside Web@Work for other apps but not for the endpoints that your app requires.